# Interacting with an open instance of Adobe DC

Tags: vb.net, adobe, com-interop

For instance, you can do this with Office via `Microsoft.Office.Interop`. My goal is to attach to any open instance of Adobe, save its PDF, then close it. I did find the Adobe SDK, but it seems a bit old and doesn't have what I want (at least I can't find anything useful).

Tried https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/sdk/eula.html (Acrobat DC SDK for Windows)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried first and what you may be stuck on.

Comment: Updated. Basically everything in the linked SDK didn't prove to do what I was expecting. There wasn't a lot in there.